# How to create hover on JLabel to show Menubar?

Tags: java

How do I make it to show a menu bar upon user hovered the cursor on a JLabel? I'm a little bit confused with the MouseEvent, etc. So here is the code:

```
public class MenuPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel fShirts, tShirts, sweater, jeans, shoes, hats, bags;
    private JButton btnCart, btnExit;
    private JPanel leftPane, rightPane;
    private Container cont;

    public MenuPage()
    {
        super ("Menu");
        cont = getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout (new BorderLayout());

        fShirts = new JLabel ("Formal Shirts", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        tShirts = new JLabel ("T - Shirts", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        sweater = new JLabel ("Sweater", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jeans = new JLabel ("Jeans", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        shoes = new JLabel ("Shoes", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        hats = new JLabel ("Hats", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        bags = new JLabel ("Bags", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        btnCart = new JButton ("Cart");
        btnExit = new JButton ("Exit");

        leftPane = new JPanel();
        leftPane.setLayout (new GridLayout (9,1));
        leftPane.setBorder (new TitledBorder ("Menus"));



        cont.add (leftPane, BorderLayout.WEST);

        leftPane.add (fShirts);
        leftPane.add (tShirts);
        leftPane.add (sweater);
        leftPane.add (jeans);
        leftPane.add (shoes);
        leftPane.add (hats);
        leftPane.add (bags);
        leftPane.add (btnCart);
        leftPane.add (btnExit);

        leftPane.setOpaque (true);

        btnCart.addActionListener(this);
        btnExit.addActionListener(this);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        validate();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent menu)
    {
        {
            if (menu.getSource() == btnCart)
            {
                dispose();
            }

            else if (menu.getSource() == btnExit)
            {
                dispose();
                new WelcomePage();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MenuPage wp = new MenuPage();
    }
}
```

How do I make the label to show up a menu bar when the user hovered the cursor on each of the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply implement a `MouseListener` (or `MouseAdapter`, which is handy) :

```
 fShirts.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hide menu");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("show menu");
        }
    });
```

By the way, your code structure would be much cleaner like this (unless you *actually* need a reference on your labels, which I doubt) :

```
public class MenuPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton                     btnCart, btnExit;
    private JPanel                      leftPane, rightPane;
    private Container                   cont;

    private static final List<String>   LABELS_TEXT = Arrays.asList("Formal Shirts","T - Shirts", //
                                                            "Sweater","Jeans","Hats","Bags");

    public MenuPage() {
        super("Menu");
        cont = getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        leftPane = new JPanel();
        leftPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,1));
        leftPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Menus"));

        List<JPopupMenu> popMenus = buildPopMenus();
        for (int i=0 ; i<LABELS_TEXT.size() ; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            JLabel label = new JLabel(LABELS_TEXT.get(i),SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    popMenus.get(j).setVisible(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point loc = label.getLocationOnScreen();
                    loc.translate(label.getWidth(),label.getHeight());
                    popMenus.get(j).setLocation(loc);
                    popMenus.get(j).setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            leftPane.add(label);
        }

        btnCart = new JButton("Cart");
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

        cont.add(leftPane,BorderLayout.WEST);
        leftPane.setOpaque(true);

        btnCart.addActionListener(this);
        btnExit.addActionListener(this);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        validate();
    }

    private List<JPopupMenu> buildPopMenus() {
        return LABELS_TEXT.stream().map(text -> { 
            JPopupMenu popMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            popMenu.add(new JMenuItem(text));
            return popMenu;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent menu) {
        if (menu.getSource() == btnCart) {
            dispose();
        }

        else if (menu.getSource() == btnExit) {
            dispose();
            // new WelcomePage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MenuPage wp = new MenuPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have created a JPopupMenu, but failed to make it appear when the cursor hovered on the JLabel.

Comment: You simply have to call `setVisible(true)` to show the menu or `setVisible(false)` to hide it.

Comment: It works, but (sorry) the menu seems to appear at the top left corner desktop, how do I make it to display exactly at the side of the JLabel.

Comment: Haha it works, but I can't click on it since it disappears when I try to approach it... Wait, I'm trying to fix it. Please accept my answer, you are now asking another question

Comment: haha that's what I'm trying to figure, then how do you make when we click on the item in the popupmenu, how do you make it to proceed to the next frame? Just like what I did with the JButton.

Comment: You should research a bit. Using a `JMenuItem` is trivial. I don't manage to solve the problem, you should ask another question for this